# Builder pattern in C# supporting subclassing with nested classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, polymorphism, immutability, fluent-interface

[Posted yesterday on Software Engineering, but was apparently "disappeared"...maybe better here]

Background: I am just starting to get my head around the idea of separating the domain model from the persistence layer (per Uncle Bob), service layer/IoC/separation of concerns/dependency injection, looking at some aspects of DDD (possibly aggregates?), enforcing invariants (e.g. having all private setters below)... *And* I'm trying to come up with some patterns that assist with those goals — ones the rest of the team can follow and adapt... I'm making multiple leaps in understanding and don't want to twist my ankle when I land.

One result of my effort is this builder pattern for large objects (lots of fields), which implements a fluent API and tries to allow for subclassing of the Builder/target pair allowing builder superclass reuse (THAT required some generics gymnastics). My thought is for a subclass of the domain model object to become a EF Core entity with persistence-specific properties and methods in the subclass, but core business logic still able to exist (and be tested) on the core domain model objects.

Some notes:

- Classes and business logic are clearly incomplete.
- The nested classes are used because they allow for private/protected member access by the Builder.
- Assume that `Id` is a store-specific property and not needed for other use cases.
- The `Builder` property on the `Event` object is mainly intended as syntactic sugar to allow clients to say `Event.Builder` instead of `new Event.EventBuilder<Event>()`.
- And if anyone wonders, I'm not going to wrap all of EF Core in a repository/UoW pattern (for now I'm buying the arguments that DbContext *is* a UoW and DbSet *is* a repository)...though I am going to put a repository wrapper around some particular entities (like audit events) that I may want to implement with a different store type.

So, here's a base `Event` class/domain model class with an inner `EventBuilder<T>` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace App.Core
{
    public class Event
    {
        public String Title { get; private set; }
        public DateTimeOffset Start { get; private set; }
        public DateTimeOffset End { get; private set; }
        // Lots more properties omitted here...
        protected Event() { }

        public static EventBuilder<Event> Builder => new Event.EventBuilder<Event>();
        public class EventBuilder<T> where T : Event
        {
            protected virtual T Result { get; set; } = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true) as T;
            public EventBuilder<T> WithTitle(String title)
            {
                Result.Title = title;
                return this;
            }

            public EventBuilder<T> WithStartAndEnd(DateTimeOffset start, DateTimeOffset end)
            {
                if (start == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(start));
                }
                if (end == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(start));
                }
                if (end < start)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(end), end, "End date must be on or after the start date.");
                }
                this.Result.Start = start;
                this.Result.End = end;
                return this;
            }
            public virtual T Create()
            {
                // Last chance validation here!
                return this.Result; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a subclass with persistence-specific features:

```
namespace App.Repository.Entities
{
    public class Event : App.Core.Event
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }

        public new static EventBuilder<Event> Builder => new Event.EventBuilder<Event>();

        public new class EventBuilder<T> : App.Core.Event.EventBuilder<T> where T : Event
        {
            //protected new T _result = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            //protected new T _result = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true) as T;
            public EventBuilder<T> WithId(int id)
            {
                this.Result.Id = id;
                return this;
            }

            public override T Create()
            {
                // Last chance validation for subclass here!
                // This is safe because we know it's operating on a subclass this.Result:
                var result = base.Create() as T;
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's some naive client code that uses the subclass:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using App.Repository.Entities; // <-- Note this namespace

namespace App.Web.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EventsController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/Event
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Event>> Get()
        {
            return new Event[] {
                Repository.Entities.Event.Builder
                    .WithId(5126)
                    .WithTitle("The Apocalypse")
                    .WithStartAndEnd(
                        new DateTimeOffset(2012, 12, 21, 6, 12, 0, new TimeSpan(-4,0,0)), 
                        new DateTimeOffset(2012, 12, 21, 6, 12, 1, new TimeSpan(-4,0,0))
                        )
                    .Create()
            };
        }
        // Other REST methods omitted...
    }
}
```

So, do you see anything glaringly stupid about the above that is going to fry me when I try to actually use it? There is certainly some naivety in the above and I would appreciate other comments/suggestions, but a good answer will point out a flaw that will make me want to substantially change the design or throw it out altogether.

Comment: One question... what is the benefit of doing this? Usually a builder simplifies _building_ complex objects or makes _raw_ APIs convenient but your solution isn't providing any of that. Since you are using this for _dtos_, I find it's much easier to just say `new Event { Property = "ABC" }` and use the _usual_ model validation for other things.

Comment: Interesting subject: I found 2 similar questions, not that this is in any way a duplicate: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133066/initializing-immutable-objects-with-a-nested-builder and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151078/generic-immutable-object-builder

Comment: @dfhwze there is one more experiment. Have you seen this insane idea too? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210056/immutable-type-updater-using-a-special-constructor :-P

Comment: @t3chb0t that one is even for your standards out of the ordinary o_0

Comment: @t3chb0t Good question. I think I know why (but have to keep checking). I've omitted many properties in the example (including many-to-many navigation properties)--to allow creation via constructor with any or all properties gets into the telescoping constructor problem and makes it (I think) hard to validate a constructed object without calling other constructors--which gets particuarly convoluted with subclasses. In this pattern I can always validate the object at the end, in `Create()`. Also, I was looking for a pattern to apply to many cases, to help myself+team keep discipline uniformly.

Comment: You have to post the complete code so that we have the full picture of your work. Until this is done, I vote to close this question as lacking context. Let's continue this topic when the question is updated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this qualifies as a review, but here we go anyways.

Don't do this. This is one of the classic use of a design pattern where we shouldn't use one. A design pattern is a solution to a known problem with set boundaries and a very specific scenario. The builder is used to build **complex** objects in a **flexible** manner. A DTO isn't a complex object and shouldn't be built in a flexible manner. If your DTOs are complex, that is the problem you should tackle with your team, not trying to find a work to work with complex DTOs.

When reading your first paragraph, I swear I could've written it 5 years ago. I've written [a generic equality checker](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60054/generic-equality-checker) (in hopes that it would help make equality comparison easier, where it's already really easy. What happened is :

1. We found edge cases that weren't supported, ended up working on it a lot more to fix the edge cases
2. It got complicated and new developers had a hard time figuring out how it worked
3. It died and is probably to this date still marked as `[Deprecated]` in a code base

Now, I ask myself three questions before I try to add a "generic" tool that'll "help" my fellow developers :

- Is the problem I'm trying to solve complex enough to require such a solution?
- Am I **100%** sure that what I've written won't explode in a mess of edge cases that'll cost more to maintain than not having the solution at all?
- Will other developers pick it up easily and understand how it works?

I'd say that 9 times out of 10, the answer is no to at least one of those questions and I end up not doing it. It takes experience to know when not to do something, because as developers we always want to work with the cool stuff, but most of the time it creates more complexity than it solves.

Now, that doesn't mean you should fiddle with ideas like these, because you can learn a lot about many things (reflection, expressions, generics, etc.). But you need to develop the reflex to ask yourself "Should this be used in a production code that'll need to be maintained for years, potentially without me?" and think *hard* about the possible consequences of using whatever you're going to build.

---

The `new` keyword is probably the biggest "maintainability danger" of the C# language (In my opinion). I really think you should use whatever other way you have not to use it (ie. removing the nested class). Use interfaces, dependency injection, etc. not to use the `new` keyword. (I'm obviously not talking about class instantiation)

Comment: Well, OP has just admitted that their code is heavily shortened so I think any review doesn't make much sense as we don't see the real complexity and the problem they're facing.

Comment: @t3chb0t Well that sucks because I took time to write my answer ahah, but I'm almost certain that whatever is added to the code won't make this builder pattern worth it.

Comment: True, your answer is so universal that whatever comes, it'll stay valid,

Comment: Thanks for this. Question... both you and @t3chb0t have referred to me using this pattern to make DTOs... But I don't see it that way, exactly... I'm planning to use this for model objects (primarily), but my pattern is to have the DTOs be a subclass of the model object, with the persistence dependencies. Is this fundamentally flawed? If (and this is not guaranteed of course), my model object's properties closely match what I want in my persistent model, maybe plus some housekeeping properties/methods?

Comment: I should add that I'm coming from using EF4 + MVC with pretty much all my business logic in the controllers... and trying to move domain logic into domain model objects and application logic into a service layer. This DTO-as-subclass model made sense to me if I could make it work, and this pattern was one part of getting there. Keeping the setters private is done to help me control state via behavioral model methods, hence I had to think about initializing an object with many properties (domain model or DTO, either way).

Comment: @S'pht'Kr yes, it is flawed. Your model class will probably be complex and validation heavy with maybe nested domain classes, where your DTOs should be dummy `{get; set;}` properties. I don't really have the space to write all the reasons I think it'll probably bounce back in your face, but think of the consequences on contravariance, covariance, on the evolution of your model objects, on the dependencies your DTO will have.

Comment: @S'pht'Kr What I mean is, sit down and try to think of all the ways it could go wrong in a month, year, 5 years, if you leave, etc and ask yourself if it's still worth it to go this way

Comment: @IEatBagels I get that... absolutely. But I'm not sure I'm convinced subclass-as-DTO is flawed just based on that comment. Maybe I need to make that a separate question over on Software Engineering. Most introductory and intermediate-level stuff using MVC + EF essentially treats the data model as *both* model object and DTO (with business logic willy-nilly all over the place), this seemed at least somewhat reasonable as a way to make that familiar while breaking the dependency on EF from the domain model layer.

Comment: @S'pht'Kr I understand your point, what I'm saying is that the experience I've had with those exact technologies and this exact mindset is that models and DTOs grow apart in the lifetime of the application and that if you couple them you end up with problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97770/discussion-between-ieatbagels-and-sphtkr).

Comment: Question on DAO-as-subclass (we were saying DTO but really it's a DAO I suppose) posted to SE.SE: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/396409/is-making-your-orm-dao-a-subclass-of-your-domain-model-object-a-viable-strategy